# Validate.js, how to override private method in typescript module

Tags: typescript, prototyping, validate.js

I'd like to use [Validate.js](https://validatejs.org/#downloads) plugin in my Typescript project. The problem is that Validate.js has method

```
collectFormValues: function (form, options)
```

with hardcoded selector for input fields and it is "name" attribute. I need to use data attr for some reasons.

```
index.d.ts
```

file contains "wrapper" interface which defines only 2 public methods so in typescript I don't have any possibility to access "collectFromValues". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it isn't exactly a "private" method, since it's listed in the validate.js documentation.  It is meant to be public, but for some reason the [type definition at DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/validate.js/index.d.ts) hasn't exposed a signature for it?  I'd say your options, in increasing order of scope, are:

- Use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) techniques to add the missing declaration(s) in your own code without messing with the `index.d.ts` file.
- Modify your local copy of `index.d.ts` to add the missing declaration(s).
- [Contribute](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/contributing.html) the improved declaration file upstream so that it can be used by everyone.

Hope that helps; good luck.